# Jquery append error message once

Tags: jquery, search, append

I've got a search field and when it is left blank and the "search" button is clicked, the error message "Please enter a search term" appears. That is what I want to happen, but when you click it again, the message is appended over and over. I want it to just append once.

This is what the jquery looks like:

```
$('#search').find('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    if( ! $('input[name=keywords]').val()){
        $('#search input[name=keywords]').addClass('error');
        $( "#search" ).append( "<p class='errorMsg top'>Please enter a search term</p>" );
        //alert('Please enter a search term');
        return false;
    } else {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onsite_search', $('input[name=keywords]').val()]); 
    }

});
```

I've tried adding this in front of the if statement:

```
for i=0; i<1; i++
```

That completely turned the functionality off. I also tried adding

```
.one('click', function{
})
```

This sort of worked -- it allowed you to click the search box once while it's empty, gave the error message, but on a second click, processed the search as "".

Any help would be much appreciated!

Also, I don't think it really matters, but here's the HTML:

```
<fieldset class="fieldset">
<legend>{lang:search_by_keyword}</legend>

<input type="text" class="input" maxlength="100" size="40" name="keywords" style="width:100%;" />

<div class="default">
<select name="search_in">
<option value="titles" selected="selected">{lang:search_in_titles}</option>
<option value="entries">{lang:search_in_entries}</option>
<option value="everywhere" >{lang:search_everywhere}</option>
</select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about having a variable that checks if the user was already warned? Then, you just append the error message if he wasn't warned already.

```
var alerted = false;

$('#search').find('input[type=submit]').click(function(){

    if( ! $('input[name=keywords]').val() && ! alerted){

        alerted = true;
        $('#search input[name=keywords]').addClass('error');
        $( "#search" ).append( "<p class='errorMsg top'>Please enter a search term</p>" );
        //alert('Please enter a search term');
        return false;
    } else {
        alerted = false; //alternatively, check if a <p> tag with class errorMsg exists and then set alerted = false
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'onsite_search', $('input[name=keywords]').val()]); 
    }

});
```

Comment: @Margaret What happens? Can you provide some more information? Maybe a Fiddle?

Comment: @Margaret Check if my edit solves the problem. The `alerted` variable needs to be outside the event, or it will be always false when it is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Use .html instead of .append when you post the error message